# How good does code have to be before sending it for code review?

Tags: software-industry

I am an intern at a software company, and someone told me to send my code out for review. My code, although functional for my current purposes, is not ready to be merged into the master branch, and contains a lot of logging statements and random stuff that should never see the light of day.

For example, I replaced one of the parameters in a function call with the number "1000" because I wasn't sure how to set the value in a more principled way. Also, the latency is really bad, so it would require substantial improvements before I could even think about deploying it.

Should I still send it for review?  I am scared people will think I am wasting their time, and/or realize I'm a bad programmer.

Comment: When you know that your code is below mediocre quality, then why do you want to send it for the review?   Trust me, this would piss off the reviewer real bad.  (Knowing the mistake and not rectifying)

Comment: Well they told me to send my code out for review a week ago, and I don't want them to think I'm not following orders.

Comment: You could have informed this to your mentor before, when they asked you for a code review.  It's not late now, but don't expect a very positive response now.  A week is a lot of wasted time at production.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [Programmers.SE]

Comment: you have had a week and not cleaned it up?

Comment: General guidelines on this probably belong on Programmers, the specific case is just "ask your manager". Voted to close as company-specific.

Comment: Absolutely not! You'll look like an idiot. Make it as good as you can first.

Comment: If you're hard-coding things, that says you or your company is not using tests appropriately. If it's the company, they should probably start there before worrying too much about code reviews.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When it's done. Or, more accurately, when it's good enough. You shall not be too picky, and some details will be forgiven to an intern, but hard-coded values? debugs? Argh, those are a no-go.

OTOH, if you're late, ask for help. I know it's one of the toughest things to do, but it's part of your job. If you did your "homework" before and can show people the progress you've mede, usually, they'll be likely to help you for the final part(a little bit like on stack overflow).

Comment: _a lot of logging statements and random stuff that should never see the light of day_ in production level code!   I wouldn't forgive even an intern, in this case!   And there's hard-coding too.

Comment: rephrased to take your excellent comment in account.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions

Comment: He might ask you for a code review to make sure you are on the right track. You should ask the purpose of this code review. He might not be expecting you to be close to finishing it.

Answer (score 4):

As you say you are already late, first thing you'd want to do is inform your mentor that you are stuck and needs help.

Do this before going to the code review, as all those bugs and backlog you have mentioned are intolerable during code reviews.

Yes, you would need to hear a word or two from your mentor as you are late by a week, and still have those irritating backlogs.

But still, come out clean.  Confess and ask help.  You are an intern, and they'd understand and would help you with that.

Comment: Part of the code review is for others to review your code and you ask any questions if you're stuck. I think the OP should go with the code review with the understanding it is not a working solution. For example, OP can walk through the code and say, "I'm stuck at point X because of Y. I understand A, B, C but cannot figure out Y."

Comment: @Dan Code reviews demand, if not perfection, but some good standards when it comes to code.  The OP's code is sub-optimal, and can't be considered worthy enough for the review.  So, he must have a talk with the mentor before the review IMO :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't listen to Dawny33, you're intern you're expected to make mistake(and this is why code review exist), the best thing you can do is sit next to the reviewer and explain your code, tell him that you successfully complete the task given, but found out that the performance is bad maybe tell him/her that you already try this and that but the performance still bad, then ask is there's another way to improve performance or how to do it the right way.

I doubt the reviewer will get angry, it's not like you do this 10 times, this is your first time, the best thing you can do now is to complete your task, listen to your reviewer/senior, and try to learn from your mistake if it happen and try not to make same mistake again.

edit: honestly I'm not bothered by logging when reviewing someone's code, I usually just told them to remove it before pushing it to development, but if you're that afraid just remove them.

Comment: +1: If you use a proper logging framework, you can usually set a logging level filter to filter out Debug logging so it's not a code smell. No logging is a code smell, imho.

Comment: Don't listen to Dawny33's comments or the answer? :)  Both are related.  You can't just walk into your mentor just like that after stalling one week of production time code activity.  You need to confess and ask for mentorship. (Yeah, I agree with your answer)

Comment: While an intern is expected to make mistakes, at least my interns are not expected to make mistakes *and not correct them even if they know about them*. It's only an honest mistake if you don't know better. If you *do* know better, it's unprofessional, even for an intern.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know, putting logging in the code and producing slow performance code doesn't sound like mistake to me.

Comment: Producing slow performance is not bad. But code review is for code that is supposedly good by the standards of the coder. If the code has problems, then you should ask for help for that specific problem, not put it under general code review in the hopes that the reviewer will eventually fix that problem as well.

Comment: Whats the point of code review if you keep expecting good code? it suppose to help find a problem, maintain a good code rule, and to learn from each other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968406/the-purpose-of-code-reviews. I'm not saying it is okay to just submit a code, but he is new, he make a lot of log, and make slow code, and the code works by the look of it this good enough to be reviewed.